# Join Similar OrderID and Aggregate Purchase Item Pandas/DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Been learning Pandas lately.
My problem is that I have a DataFrame consisting of 'OrderID' and 'Purchase Item'
I want it to GroupBy OrderID and also joining the PurchasedItem together into one column with the OrderID.

```
dupRow_1['Grouped'] = dupRow_1.groupby('Order ID')['Product'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Used the code above but I am getting Length Mismatch Error:
"Length mismatch: Expected axis has 15004 elements, new values have 15549 elements"

Any idea how I can do this? Thank you.

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js8pQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are missing values in `Order ID` column, so rows are excluded by `groupby`. So you can replace them by some value not exist in data, e.g. `missing`:

```
dupRow_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Product':list('abcdef'),
         'Order ID':[np.nan,5,4,5,5,np.nan],

})
dupRow_1['Grouped'] = (dupRow_1['Product'].groupby(dupRow_1['Order ID'].fillna('missing'))
                                          .transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)))

print (dupRow_1)
  Product  Order ID Grouped
0       a       NaN     a,f
1       b       5.0   b,d,e
2       c       4.0       c
3       d       5.0   b,d,e
4       e       5.0   b,d,e
5       f       NaN     a,f
```

Comment: That works. I believe the FillNA('missing') did the job. I didn't thought about if there might be NA in the data. Thank you.